# Unable to view page in browser from Views

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I've created the following folder and page in my MVC Core application:
Views->Adminstration->CreateRole.cshtml

I'm not bale to view the page in my browser after rebuilding it.

```
This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44310/Administration/createrole.cshtml
HTTP ERROR 404
```

could it be something in my routing or what could be the problem ?

startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
            IHostingEnvironment env, ApplicationDbContext context, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            // 
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            SeedIdentity.Initialize(context, userManager, roleManager).Wait();
        }
```

The AdministrationController below:

```
 public class AdministrationController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        public AdministrationController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            //_roleManager = roleManager;
            //_userManager = userManager;
        }
        /**
        public AdministrationController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            this.roleManager = roleManager;
        }**/

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult CreateRole()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(CreateRoleViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityRole identityRole = new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = model.RoleName
                };
                IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }
                foreach (IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }

            }


            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: You need to have an `AdminstrationController` controller with a `createrole` action to return View.Besides, the url should not have `.cshtml`, it should be `https://localhost:44310/Administration/createrole`

Comment: I have the account controller and did try it without .cshtml

Comment: Since the url is `/controller/action` you need to have correspond controller name and action name